# Ajaxify quicktabs does not work when views have contextual filters

Tags: 7, blocks

I have 4 views and i have made them into tabs using quicktabs and it works fine. But when i try to load then through ajax starting from second views nothing loads.I have some contextual filters in all these views. Is this effecting it? If so how do i get over it ?